# Nest.js deployment using multiple lambda functions

Tags: node.js, serverless

I have deployed Nest.js application with serverless using one function . Now issue is that my code repository is being growing and I'm now getting lambda memory limit error . So I want to deploy my nest.js app using multiple lambda functions.

My solutions is to place separate serverless.yml file into each module is that solution will work or I need to do something else ?

Comment: Hi, do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Monolithic-functions vs mulitple single function are explained in detailed on [this link](https://hackernoon.com/aws-lambda-should-you-have-few-monolithic-functions-or-many-single-purposed-functions-8c3872d4338f)

I will also recommend you look at http less implementation of Nest.JS to further reduce the overhead